# How to calculate the walking distance in android?

Tags: android, dictionary, gps

I am working on a step counter app like the following

[image]

So far I found some solution like the following:

```
private void GetDistance(GeoPoint src, GeoPoint dest) {

    StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
    urlString.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?");
    urlString.append("origin=");//from
    urlString.append( Double.toString((double)src.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append( Double.toString((double)src.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6));
    urlString.append("&destination=");//to
    urlString.append( Double.toString((double)dest.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append( Double.toString((double)dest.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6));
    urlString.append("&mode=walking&sensor=true");
    Log.d("xxx","URL="+urlString.toString());

    // get the JSON And parse it to get the directions data.
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection= null;
    URL url = null;

    url = new URL(urlString.toString());
    urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.connect();

    InputStream inStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));

    String temp, response = "";
    while((temp = bReader.readLine()) != null){
        //Parse data
        response += temp;
    }
    //Close the reader, stream & connection
    bReader.close();
    inStream.close();
    urlConnection.disconnect();

    //Sortout JSONresponse 
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
    JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("routes");
        //Log.d("JSON","array: "+array.toString());

    //Routes is a combination of objects and arrays
    JSONObject routes = array.getJSONObject(0);
        //Log.d("JSON","routes: "+routes.toString());

    String summary = routes.getString("summary");
        //Log.d("JSON","summary: "+summary);

    JSONArray legs = routes.getJSONArray("legs");
        //Log.d("JSON","legs: "+legs.toString());

    JSONObject steps = legs.getJSONObject(0);
            //Log.d("JSON","steps: "+steps.toString());

    JSONObject distance = steps.getJSONObject("distance");
        //Log.d("JSON","distance: "+distance.toString());

            String sDistance = distance.getString("text");
            int iDistance = distance.getInt("value");

}
```

I decided to use GPS way to implement.
However, what is the "common way" to implement this?  Is it just getting the gps lat, lan at say 30 second, then calcuate the differance? 
e.g. How long is the interval between getting the GPS data.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling google api you can use method for calculating distance.

```
public double getDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    double latA = Math.toRadians(lat1);
    double lonA = Math.toRadians(lon1);
    double latB = Math.toRadians(lat2);
    double lonB = Math.toRadians(lon2);
    double cosAng = (Math.cos(latA) * Math.cos(latB) * Math.cos(lonB-lonA)) +
                (Math.sin(latA) * Math.sin(latB));
    double ang = Math.acos(cosAng);
    double dist = ang *6371;
    return dist;
}
```

This will reduce the one API call and quick way to find the distance between two positions.

Comment: How frequent should I get the gps data?

Comment: 30 Seconds is best one. You can set which is suitable to you. only thing is you need to calculated distance whenever you get new location update.

Answer (score 2):

Do this function

```
 getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
 var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
 var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
 var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
 var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
 Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
 Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
 var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
 var d = R * c; // Distance in km
return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
```